# Pyspark can't read a parquet file with a UUID in it

Tags: pyspark, azure-synapse

I have a Azure Synapse Notebook that I'm running pyspark in to process a parquet input file.  I can read the file with a schema, but the UUID comes back as gibberish.  If I don't provide a schema I get an `Illegal Parquet type: FIXED_LEN_BYTE_ARRAY` Here is my code that gets the FIXED_LEN_BYTE_ARRAY error:

```
SourceFilePath = f'abfss://datalake@' + AzureBlobStorageAccountName + '.dfs.core.windows.net/Bronze/ServiceBus/' + SourceFileName

dfBronze = spark.read.load(SourceFilePath, format='parquet').cache()

dfBronze.createOrReplaceTempView("Bronze")
```

And this code basically allows me to ignore the CorrelationId/GUID/UUID:

```
SourceFilePath = f'abfss://datalake@' + AzureBlobStorageAccountName + '.dfs.core.windows.net/Bronze/ServiceBus/' + SourceFileName
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, BooleanType, IntegerType, ArrayType, TimestampType, LongType

schema = StructType([
    StructField('Created', TimestampType(), True),
    StructField('Entity', StringType(), True),
    StructField('EntityId', IntegerType(), True),
    StructField('Version', IntegerType(), True),
    StructField('CorrelationId', StringType(), True)
])

dfBronze = spark.read.format("parquet").schema(schema).load(SourceFilePath)

dfBronze.createOrReplaceTempView("Bronze")

dfBronze.show()
```

How do I read a parquet file with a UUID in it into a dataframe?

Comment: try giving the CorrelationId ID as binarydata type and see

Comment: BinaryType() gave me the same `Illegal Parquet type: FIXED_LEN_BYTE_ARRAY` error message on the `dfBronze.show()`

Comment: can you show values for CorrelationId ID?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for?  This is what the CorrelationId looks like in the parquet file.  Just replace the numbers below to make additional test data `"Version": 0,
"CorrelationId": {
    "type": "Buffer",
    "data": [
        59,
        241,
        154,
        45,
        112,
        213,
        101,
        75,
        159,
        190,
        172,
        52,
        175,
        100,
        168,
        189
    ]`